# Is React Native broken or is it just me? Tried versions 0.19.0 - 0.15.0, all give errors

Tags: react-native

I developed a project with RN 0.8.0 and Xcode 6.4, and was trying to get people to test it using Test Flight. The friends testing on an iPhone5 and 6 were just getting a white screen, and sure enough when I tried the simulator for an iPhone5, it crashes when opening (even though it's fine on the 4s and 5s simulators I was testing with).  I then decided to upgrade RN to see if that would help.

I followed the directions on their "Upgrading" page to install the latest RN (0.19), and upgraded to Xcode 7.0.1.  When running the project I get a compile error about RCTRootView, so I look it up and perform the appropriate fix as suggested, then I get an error about file not found linker command error.

I wonder what's going on, so I try to make a blank project by using the `react-native init` command to initialize a **brand new project** in a different folder, which *should* run fine because I haven't touched it.  Well, I get an error with that too (with  __fbBatchedBridge).  I downgrade to 0.18.0, same error.  I downgrade to 0.17.0, and it compiles, but I get a blank white screen on the simulator (without the "Welcome to React Native!" message I should be seeing).  I then downgrade to 0.15.0, and get two compile errors in the tests.m file (Unknown type name 'RCTLogSource' and incompatible block pointer types).  I haven't even touched the project, so it seems React Native is downloading broken files.

Anyone know what might be going on?  Why are the brand new RN projects broken even though I haven't touched them? How can I get RN working again, short of wiping my system and starting from scratch?

Comment: What version of node and npm are you using ?

Comment: Node v 5.6.0 and npm 3.6.0

Comment: The fbBatchedBridge error is on iOS or android ?

Comment: It is all running on iOS.

Comment: Could you show the error you get on version 0.19 of RN ? The linker error is on which file ?

Comment: The test project with 0.19.0 has an error with __fbBatchedBridge.  I put the error log here: http://pastebin.com/52nG9L6a

Comment: Moved on to a new machine and installed 0.20.0 fresh.  Don't get that error any more.  Must have been the upgrade from 0.8.0 to 0.19.0, being a huge jump